# Questions about Hausdorff measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I wonder if I can use Hausdorff dimension to conclude that the measure of a graph of a measurable function $$ G_{f}=\left\{ \left(x,f\left(x\right)\right)\thinspace:\thinspace x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{k+1} $$

is of measure $0$ by the $ m^{k+1}$ measure (Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$).

Given such $f$, define the function $$ \Phi:\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}^{k+1} $$.

$$ \Phi\left(x\right)=\left(x,f\left(x\right)\right) $$
$\Phi$ is measurable since its composition with projections is measurable, and the graph of $f$ is the image of $\Phi$.

My intuition, is that since $\Phi$ is measurable, its image $\Phi(\mathbb{R}^k)$ cannot have Hausdorff dimension greater than $k$, and thus the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, which is just Hasudorff measure of dimension $k+1$ (up to a contant factor), would yield measure 0.

How can I justify that indeed the image of $\Phi$ cannot have greater Hausdorff dimension than $k$?

Comment: You do not need Hausdorff here. Just use Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know. But I want too look at it from the Hausdorff perspective.

Comment: You can't, see f.i. here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23960/how-big-can-the-hausdorff-dimension-of-a-function-graph-get